# How to scroll to a specific record in a treegrid with smartgwt when it's initially drawed?

Tags: scroll, smartgwt, treegrid

I need to draw a tree grid with selecting and scrolling to a specific record initially. I tried the following code. The selection works, but the scrolling doesn't. What is the solution?

```
    treeGrid.addDataArrivedHandler(new DataArrivedHandler() {  
        public void onDataArrived(DataArrivedEvent event) {  
            TreeNode node = treeGrid.getData().find("ID", id);  
            treeGrid.selectRecord(node);
            treeGrid.scrollToRow(treeGrid.getRecordIndex(node));

            }
        }  
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with a ListGrid and solved it by wrapping the scrollToRow command in this:

```
DeferredCommand.addCommand(new Command() {
  public void execute() {
     grid.scrollToRow();
  }
};
```

solution found [here.](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=11353)

Answer (score 0):

now DeferredCommand is deprecated, so...

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Command() {
    public void execute() {
        grid.scrollToRow();
    }
});
```

will be better.